# I can't get VSCode to open window for snake script

Tags: python

I am practicing some very simple projects and I found the snake game and handed to try my hand. I am pretty sure I copied the code completely but when I run it a small blue screen pops up for a split second and then disappears and doesn't say what's wrong.
site I am using for the project. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-snake-game-using-turtle-in-python/

```
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
score = 0
high_score = 0

# creating a window screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game")
wn.bgcolor("blue")

# Width and height 
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# head of the snake
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "Stop"


# food in the game
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red', 'green', 'black'])
shapes = random.choice(['square', 'Triangle', 'circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 250)
pen.write ("Score : 0 High Score : 0", align="center", 
      font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a blue screen because the code is not complete there are some variables missing + the main game loop doesn't exits so the game simply crashes here is the complete code I got it from the same website further down [Full Code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-snake-game-using-turtle-in-python/#highlighter_325008)

```
# import required modules
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
score = 0
high_score = 0



# Creating a window screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game")
wn.bgcolor("blue")
# the width and height can be put as user's choice
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# head of the snake
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "Stop"

# food in the game
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red', 'green', 'black'])
shapes = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 250)
pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0", align="center",
        font=("candara", 24, "bold"))



# assigning key directions
def group():
    if head.direction != "down":
        head.direction = "up"


def godown():
    if head.direction != "up":
        head.direction = "down"


def goleft():
    if head.direction != "right":
        head.direction = "left"


def goright():
    if head.direction != "left":
        head.direction = "right"


def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+20)
    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-20)
    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-20)
    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+20)


        
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(group, "w")
wn.onkeypress(godown, "s")
wn.onkeypress(goleft, "a")
wn.onkeypress(goright, "d")

segments = []



# Main Gameplay
while True:
    wn.update()
    if head.xcor() > 290 or head.xcor() < -290 or head.ycor() > 290 or head.ycor() < -290:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0, 0)
        head.direction = "Stop"
        colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
        shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segment.goto(1000, 1000)
        segments.clear()
        score = 0
        delay = 0.1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
            score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
    if head.distance(food) < 20:
        x = random.randint(-270, 270)
        y = random.randint(-270, 270)
        food.goto(x, y)

        # Adding segment
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("orange") # tail colour
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)
        delay -= 0.001
        score += 10
        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
            score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
    # Checking for head collisions with body segments
    for index in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x, y)
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x, y)
    move()
    for segment in segments:
        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0, 0)
            head.direction = "stop"
            colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
            shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])
            for segment in segments:
                segment.goto(1000, 1000)
            segment.clear()

            score = 0
            delay = 0.1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
                score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
    time.sleep(delay)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a game loop, in the tutorial you linked to the code block you have showed was only the setup if you continue scrolling down there is more code containing functions that handle user input as well as a game loop.  Here is the full program in their tutorial.

```py
# import required modules
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1
score = 0
high_score = 0



# Creating a window screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game")
wn.bgcolor("blue")
# the width and height can be put as user's choice
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# head of the snake
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "Stop"

# food in the game
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red', 'green', 'black'])
shapes = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 250)
pen.write("Score : 0 High Score : 0", align="center",
    font=("candara", 24, "bold"))



# assigning key directions
def group():
    if head.direction != "down":
         head.direction = "up"


def godown():
    if head.direction != "up":
        head.direction = "down"


def goleft():
    if head.direction != "right":
        head.direction = "left"


def goright():
    if head.direction != "left":
        head.direction = "right"


def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+20)
    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-20)
    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-20)
    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+20)


        
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(group, "w")
wn.onkeypress(godown, "s")
wn.onkeypress(goleft, "a")
wn.onkeypress(goright, "d")

segments = []



# Main Gameplay
while True:
    wn.update()
    if head.xcor() > 290 or head.xcor() < -290 or head.ycor() > 290 or head.ycor() < -290:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0, 0)
        head.direction = "Stop"
        colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
        shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segment.goto(1000, 1000)
        segments.clear()
        score = 0
        delay = 0.1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
            score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
    if head.distance(food) < 20:
        x = random.randint(-270, 270)
        y = random.randint(-270, 270)
        food.goto(x, y)

        # Adding segment
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("orange") # tail colour
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)
        delay -= 0.001
        score += 10
        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
            score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
    # Checking for head collisions with body segments
    for index in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x, y)
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x, y)
    move()
    for segment in segments:
        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0, 0)
            head.direction = "stop"
            colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
            shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])
            for segment in segments:
                segment.goto(1000, 1000)
            segment.clear()

            score = 0
            delay = 0.1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
                score, high_score), align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
    time.sleep(delay)

wn.mainloop()
```